# Any way to display multiple cells if value is a number or lower and isn't TRUE?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to have two cells from each line show up on a separate list if a checkbox is unchecked, and prioritize them in numerical value, from descending to ascending in google sheets.

[image]

I currently have this spreadsheet pulling from individual sheets and outputting their values. I am having trouble figuring out what I need to to do make a separate list that shows the lowest value first (In column C (HC Tier)) while retaining a value (Name) next to it (Column A (Tanks/Healers)) and the highest value (In column C (HC Tier)) last.

I'm not the most experienced with any spreadsheets and would like some assistance.

For additional reference, this is the desired output (Shown in column G and H):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv7b5.png)

Information pulling for Columns (Example is for Hyphra):
A: `='T5-Tanks'!B1`
B: `=COUNTIF('T5-Tanks'!B5:B9, TRUE)`
C: `=COUNTIF('T5-Tanks'!C5:C9, TRUE)`
D: `=COUNTIF('T5-Tanks'!D5:D9, TRUE)`
E: Checkbox

Information is pulled from additional Tabs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yLH2.png)

Comment: What about if sort data from data tab?

Comment: I'm okay with that, but would need to have it trigger from this tab, and would need it to display on this tab as well.

If adding another tab to handle the calculations would make this possible, I'm more than willing to make that happen.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Public Copy

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d5wAEAgjSed-brpJxnfkPmAMETakm8WCZFiIKe1xLnk/edit?usp=sharing

Looking to have Column A and C display in a different chart on the same sheet, in relevance to the following:

- 0's for column C being on top

- 5's for column C being on bottom

- Retaining the matching Name in column A to column C

- Ignore columns A and C from bodies above if 'Ignore' tab is checked (Resulting in TRUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything from Col G and Col H (including the headers). Then place the following formula in G1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Players",C1; IFERROR(SORT(FILTER({A:A,C:C},A:A<>"",ISNUMBER(C:C),E:E<>TRUE),2,1),{"",""})})`

Note that your existing "Desired results" list is missing the name "Rosaile" while the above formula includes it.

`=ArrayFomrula({   ;   })` is the structure for setting up an array result with header(s) to the left of the semicolon and result(s) to the right of the semicolon.

`"Players",C1` creates the headers (i.e., the words "Players" beside the value found in cell C1).

`FILTER` sets up an array formula of just Col A beside Col C, including only those results where Col A is not null, Col C contains a number AND Col E is not checked.

`SORT` sorts this by the second (numeric) column in ascending order.

`IFERROR` returns null for both columns if an error occurs.

Comment: You are a godsent. Thank you very much for the rapid response and thank you for explaining what each thing does.

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy.